# Recieving id from database won't work, while I can recieve other database fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little question. I've been working with PHP & MYSQL for a while. But now something weird has happened.

I have a database, with the table: categories. It looks like this:

```
id       title        description
1        CSS          -
2        CSS3         -
3        HTML         -
4        HTML5        -
5        PHP          -
6        JAVA         -
```

So, now I have made a connection which works because this works:

http://prntscr.com/6jhwq8

Then in my browser, on the first eye.. It looks to work, but it only adds the 'title' in the (li)(/li), it doesn't add the 'id' in the (a)(/a), as you can see here:

http://prntscr.com/6jhzwx

I hope someone can help me out here.

Kind Regards!

Comment: Can't see nuffin' on those links.

Comment: You have 3 's in those hrefs. That might be a problem. If not, paste a var_dump of one $row as well as raw HTML output of the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those links aren't the most helpful, but the problem comes from quotes. You will see it if you "view source" in your browser.

You are creating HTML that looks like this:

```
<li><a href='cat.php?id='...
```

Notice that you are putting the same single-quote that you started your href value with - you are also using it to surround your id. No go. Probably you don't need the single quotes around your id at all.